# Calculate the duration of a session in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, duration

I have table containing sessionid and datetime.

[image: (A=>2h, B=>3h, C=1h)]

I want to calculate the duration of a session.

The duration of a session is defined by measuring the time from the first to the last occurrence of a SessionId.

How should i find the first and last occurrence of a session and how should i calculate the duration of a session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility without altering your table. Create a visual where SessionID is at least one of your components, e.g. a table with rows for each Session ID. Add the following measure:

```
Sessionlength = DATEDIFF( MIN ( table[DateTime] ), MAX ( table[DateTime] ), HOUR )
```

Answer (score 0):

Original Data

[image]

Then I did group by Session Id

[image]

Then I had table grouped as below

[image]

At last I added new column and it gives date diff between grouped min and max dates
We have our desired result.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I couldn't group by session id due to using Power Query.